# VSTS throttling issue

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

Hi im migrating a github repository to a Visual Studio Online TFS server, im using a tool called git-tf. My problem is that VSTS puts a limit on usage of the server, and because of this puts a delay on my process making it take ages. Im wondering if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: Not sure what "usage limit" you're talking about. Also, it's worth noting that Git-TF is effectively deprecated; Git-TFS is better.

Comment: What's the result if you import repository directly?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Import repository feature in VSTS:

[Import a Git repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-git-repository)